# Custom Price appears in Cart just after refresh

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

The problem is that the **custom price** appears in Cart, only after **refreshing** this one.

I have the following code which sets custom price :

---

```
           $item->setBaseSubtotal($price);

           $item->setCustomPrice($price);
           $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
           $item->setPrice($price);
           $item->setIsSuperMode(true);

           $item->save();

           $this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
           $this->cart->getQuote()->collectTotals();
           $this->cart->getQuote()->save();

           $this->cart->save();
```

---

In Cart I have the default price (not updated) but in the Total Order I have the right prices. 
Once the cart is updated, both are correct.

Has someone any idea how to set this problem?

Comment: Which event you are using for adding your custom price?

Comment: I'm using a Controller, not an Event to add my custom price.

Comment: Please add details about which controller action you are using.

Comment: First, I get and match product reference, then I add the product object with reference in cart object. And finally I save the cart. When this is done, I have the item in cart and I set its prices with the code above.